# Option value Not displaying in drop-down menu?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm using a date range on a web page to aggregate MySQL data and present it based on the selected time frame. For some reason the values for each option in the drop-down menus are not displaying. Here's the PHP I'm using:

```
<select name="date1" title="<?=$date1 ?>">
<?php foreach($availableDates as $date) { ?>
<option value="<?=$date ?>"<?php if($date == $date1) { ?> selected="selected"<?php } ?><?=$date ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

And here's the HTML output:

```
<option value="2015-01-03" selected="selected" 2015-01-03<="" option=""></option>
```

The weirdest part is this was working for the longest time and suddenly the dates in both menus vanished. Any ideas why?

Comment: Do you see closing `>` for `<option`? I don't.

Comment: close the option start tag.

Comment: This would be more obvious if you were to get rid of the terrible shorthand method. Format your code in a decent fashion and you will spot errors like this more quickly.

Comment: This is inherited code but I should've caught that regardless. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

This happened becuase you are missing the ending **>** of  tag

**Modified code:**

```
<select name="date1" title="<?=$date1 ?>">
<?php foreach($availableDates as $date) { ?>
<option value="<?=$date ?>"<?php if($date == $date1) { ?> selected="selected"<?php } ?>>
<?=$date ?>
</option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP snippet is missing a closing `>`:

```
<select name="date1" title="<?=$date1 ?>">
  <?php foreach($availableDates as $date) { ?>
  <option 
    value="<?=$date ?>"
    <?php if($date == $date1) { ?> selected="selected"<?php } ?>
  >
    <?=$date ?>
  </option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this way also :**

```
<select name="per1" id="per1">
  <option selected="selected">Choose one</option>
  <?php
    foreach($names as $name) { ?>
      <option value="<?= $name['name'] ?>"><?= $name['name'] ?></option>
  <?php
    } ?>
</select>
```

Now you can put your code here.

Comment: No my friend I am talking about if date == date1 than this particular option will selected... u missed it. :)

Comment: then put a condition in it <?php if($date == $date1)  ?>

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Add `>` tag closer after selected attribute
**2.** Remove shorthanded `<?= ?>` tag which is unwanted while you also using `<?php ?>`

```
<select name="date1" title="<?php print $date1; ?>">
    <?php foreach($availableDates as $date) { 
        ?><option value="<?php print $date; ?>"<?php if($date == $date1) { ?> selected="selected"<?php } ?>>
            <?php print $date; ?>
        </option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this less error prone code.

```
$selHTML = '<select name="date1" title="'.$date1.'">';
foreach($availableDates as $date) { 
  $sel = ($date == $date1)?" selected":"";
  $selHTML .= '<option value="'.$date.'"'.$sel.'>'.$date.'</option>';
}
$selHTML .= '</select>';
echo $selHTML;
```